# Running turtlebot on a roomba, launch file?

Tags: ros, roomba, roslaunch, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a roomba 780 that I am trying to run turtlebot on. I have been able to install the turtlebot fuerte on the both pc and I can ssh into the turtlebot computer, so all communication parts are set and are working. But when I start the turtlebot  nothing happens , I can start the turtlebot service so it run but i cant comunicate with my roomba. I think i know/have read that you have to change the communication speed and also tell in the launch file that you have a roomba and that it has no gyro.

However I have no clue how to change the launch file. I have done the basic tutorials, but still not getting how I create or edit the launch file?! Some help or guidance to where on the forum i find this info would be very appreciated

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45549/running-turtlebot-on-a-roomba,-launch-file?/) by [krst](https://answers.ros.org/users/3315/krst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krst](https://answers.ros.org/users/3315/krst/) on 2012-10-11**:
Many thanks Lorenz, I am still however little confused where to put and create the launch file? Because when i tried to edit the launch file in the etc/ros folder it was write protected the folder and file. I assume I am doing this completly wrong the launch file creation?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-11**:
Just put the launch file somewhere and execute it with `roslaunch`. Make sure that no other turtlebot related stuff is running to avoid conflicts.

**Comment by [krst](https://answers.ros.org/users/3315/krst/) on 2012-10-14**:
I am seeing that I get the error message [Distance, angle displacement too big, invalid readings from robot. Distance: 1.84, Angle: -21.02]. I have a memory that i have seen this here before on the forum but cant find the post...  When i look at the node.py this error message I thought only would come for a create?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-14**:
Please do not delete a complete question and replace it by a new question to not lose the connection between questions and answers. Instead, please create a new question.

**Comment by [krst](https://answers.ros.org/users/3315/krst/) on 2012-10-15**:
Ok sorry, I saw it as an extentions of the same topic but I will edit back and do that instead!  Thanks!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-15**:
I think it's just important to keep the old question. If you want, you can of course edit it and add further information. But in case you have a separate, although maybe related question, I guess it's better to open a new question. That's what this site is all about in the end :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure how different the communication protocols between the roomba 780 and the roomba 530 are. You could try the following launch file to bring up the robot's base driver:

```
<launch>
  <node name="turtlebot_node" type="turtlebot_node.py" pkg="turtlebot_node">
    <rosparam>
      port: /dev/ttyUSB0
      publish_tf: True
      robot_type: roomba
      has_gyro: False
    </rosparam>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Make sure that the usb port is correct. If launching the file does not throw an error, `rostopic echo /odom` should publish data and you should be able to teleop the robot. If you are getting errors, I guess the communication protocol changed. In that case you might have to patch the turtlebot driver. Patches welcome :)

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1